# IfxPy installation fails

Tags: python-3.x, windows, pip, informix

I have the same problem.

```
C:>pip install IfxPy ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement IfxPy (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for IfxPy
```

It was working on Python2.7 but now I have Python3.8.6 installed and I can't use IfxPy. I tried to install using pip and directly with "python setup.py install" on the zip file without success. Can you help me?

```
C:>python -V Python 3.8.6

C:>pip -V pip 20.2.3 from c:\python 3.8\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

C:>pip3 -V pip 20.2.3 from c:\python 3.8\lib\site-packages\pip (python 3.8)

C:>set PATH Path=C:\Python 3.8\Scripts;C:\Python 3.8;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\lib64;C:\Program Files\ibm\gsk8\bin;C:\Program Files\Informix Client-SDK;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Oracle806\bin;C:\Progra~1\Oracle\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Python27;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64;C:\Users\p054007\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Scripts;C:\Users\p054007\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32;C:\Oracle806\bin;C:\Progra~1\Oracle\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Python27;C:\Users\p054007\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Users\p054007\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
set PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.PY;.PYW
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest release of `IfxPy` (currently [3.0.3](https://pypi.org/project/IfxPy/3.0.3/#files) provides only wheels for 64-bit Python 3.7 for Windows and 64-bit Python 3.8 for Linux.

Install it with 64-bit Python 3.7 for Windows. Or [compile from sources](https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy/blob/master/LocalBuildWindows.md).